# Turn off non-Wifi Internet access on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to use internet only via Wifi, and be asked if I want to use the internet via my SIM (3G or so).

How can I do that? Is there a setting for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can turn off cellular data (or your internet over your SIM) when you go to Settings->Cellular (or Mobile data) and then turn of Cellular data.
Or in Romanian:
Configurari->Conexiune celulara and turn off Date celulare

this way you'll use only your wifi connection (if you're connected to WiFi).

Comment: Is it the same with "Mobile Data"? I cannot find "Cellular" in my settings. I'm using iPhone SE.

Comment: what software version do you have on your device? you can see it on Settings->general->about

Comment: I'm using `9.3.2 (13F69)`.

Comment: Then you should have Cellular in settings... Is your SIM card in the phone?

Comment: Yes, it's there and everything works fine. I just want to make sure this won't eat my `$` when I'm not connected to WiFi. It's my first smartphone. :)

Comment: No problem :) there should be Cellular in Settings for sure, I have 3 iPhone SE's in front of me with this version.

Comment: I uploaded few screenshots here: http://m.imgur.com/u2RlYSI,EAJ0dSA,wmXTJLb,fGfZNnn,timbsnJ

Comment: Then it's mobile data in your case :)

Comment: OK, thanks :) Don't forget to update your answer with that, then. I asked a new question, maybe you can help there as well: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/242739/87092