# Share music between Macbook and iPhone

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, ios, macos

I'm trying to figure out how to get some music on my iPhone SE from my Macbook.

I have the music on my Macbook drive and I can listen to it in iTunes. How can I sync it with my iPhone and make it available on iPhone even when connected to internet or to my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you connect your iPhone to iTunes and Sync :)
Start iTunes, connect iPhone via USB cable to USB on your computer, when your phone (after few confirmations on phone) appears in iTunes click on it. Then on the right side select Music, check Sync music and choose what you want to sync.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to connect my iPhone without the USB cable? All usb ports are currently busy on my mac.

Comment: First time you sync you have to use USB cable, then you can set syncing over WiFi, more info at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203075